# font rendering issue

Tags: font, type

I have been designing the UI for a financial application. I'd usually do high-fidelity mockups using Photoshop and send them to the developers. What I have noticed is that the text in the actual product looks different from my mockups, but they are in fact the same font. The left image is the high-fi mockup, using Arial. The right image is the actual product, also in Arial. I tried all the different anti-aliasing options, but none gets me close to the image on the right. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

[image]

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. If not, can someone please direct me to an appropriate source? Thank you!

Comment: This should probably be moved to Graphic Design.

Comment: It strikes me as more of a programming question, related to the specific tools and environment used to create the app.  That information would be needed to answer it adequately.

Comment: Assuming you don't have bold selected on one and not the other. I would guess that photshop version is using a different dpi then the product.  Presumably photoshop is rounding up on pixels while your product is stable or rounding down.

Comment: James Jenkins should add your comment as a answer

Comment: I've closed this without migrating it as it's a graphic design concern and it's already been asked over on Graphic design (where it was closed as there's already a question with answers for this issue): http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21017/font-rendering-issue